# How to transfer Diablo 3 savegames?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there any way I can transfer my current progress in game from one PC to another.
During day I am playing on my office computer and in the evening on my personal computer at home? Any idea where the savegame files are located or how this works?

The issue is that when I log in from another PC with the same account I don't have the characters.

Comment: You play in the office on office property? What does your boss think of that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The game is saved online on blizzards server, so when you stop you can continue from same quest on any other machine, any progression between checkpoints is lost.

It is most likely your region that is set to two different regions on each game, make sure they both have the same region.

Comment: The issue is that when I log in from another PC with the same account I don't have the caracters ex : level 10 barbarian and current game progress form my home computer. I need to start from zero.

I wanted to somehow transfer the game progress between different PC for the same account.

Comment: It is most likely because you have region set up wrong, go to options and check what region you have your game set to. Personally I had to change my region from The Americas to Europe even though I downloaded the EU client

Comment: My office setting is EU, I need to check to one from home, but I know I used the client to download the game at home, so it's very possible this is it.I will check, thanks.

Comment: It worked! thanks! I actually changed my office setting to The Americas  and I got my character